# IBrokers enabling Delayed market data?

Tags: r, ibrokers

I'm trying to download data from IBrokers but currently getting an error. I'm not sure how to solve it.

Note: 
I don't have a subscription to live quotes but I do get delayed market data.

My steps are:

```
security = twsSTK("AAPL")
is.twsContract(security)
```

[1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/IBrokers.pdf) TRUE

```
security_copy= twsEquity('AAPL')
reqMktData(tws,security)
```

Error output:

> TWS Message: 2 1 162 Historical Market Data Service error message:No
>   market data permissions for ISLAND STK  TWS Message: 2 1 366 No
>   historical data query found for ticker id:1  TWS Message: 2 1 10168
>   Requested market data is not subscribed. Delayed market data is not
>   enabled

The historical data function also seems to have issues.

```
data_AAPL=reqHistoricalData(tws, security)
```

I have also tried the example in [Link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/IBrokers.pdf)

```
 IBrokersRef() # IBrokers Reference Card in PDF viewer
 tws <- twsConnect() # make a new connection to the TWS
 reqCurrentTime(tws) # check the server's timestamp
 contract <- twsEquity('IBKR','SMART','ISLAND') # equity specification
 reqHistoricalData(tws,contract) # request historical data
```

Result:

> waiting for TWS reply on IBKR ....failed. NULL Warning message: In
>   errorHandler(con, verbose, OK = c(165, 300, 366, 2104, 2106,  :
>   Historical Market Data Service error message:No market data
>   permissions for ISLAND

Answer (score 1):

Based on TWS documentation ([here](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/market_data_type.html)) one can get delayed market data using reqMarketDataType(4).

That being said I would recommend using the ib_insync package from Ewald de Wit & Co.

Below is an code example I use to fetch delayed market data :

```
from ib_insync import *

util.startLoop()

ib = IB()
ib.sleep(2)
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', port=7490, clientId=12) # NB: Non default port could be 7498 on your machine by default when using TWS

ib.reqMarketDataType(4) # This line is the one that counts to get delayed data without subscription if available
```